# AWS Amplify DataStore displaying as-it-is string data with '\n' (New line character) without creating a new line in Flutter 'Text' class

Tags: flutter, text, aws-amplify, datastore, flutter-text

I've a small doubt on displaying data through AWS Amplify DataStore.

I've the below model in schema.graphql

```
type ItemFaq @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  indexItemFaq: Int
  titleItemFaq: String
  subtitleItemFaq: String
}
```

I've deployed data model in AWS Amplify and updated sample data with new line character - as shown below:
[image]

In my Flutter App, I wanted to show data in newline using Flutter '[Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)' class, but instead I'm getting the data retrieved from AWS Amplify as shown below:
[image]

How can I make use of Flutter 'Text' class to show data in new line when retrieving data from AWS Amplify?

Comment: Can you try setting the 'Text' property 'softWrap' to true? may you also try it without space? so ABC\nDEF instead of ABC \n DEF

Comment: Hey @Texv, I tried putting 'softWrap: true,' inside of the 'Text' class and tried to update data without spaces - but it's still not displaying data on newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text(
'subtitle'.replaceAll('\\n', '\n'),
),
```

Comment: Thank you @Texv! I tried using ".replaceAll('\\n', '\n')" and it worked like a charm.